# Launch a command in bash script with variables containing double quotes

Tags: bash, command, quotes

I made this very simple script to illustrate my problem

```
#!/bin/bash
filelist=("\"test 1.jpg\"" "\"test 2.jpg\"")
echo ${filelist[@]:0:2}
ls ${filelist[@]:0:2}|grep 1
```

The issue is bash adds single quotes to my ls command :

> ls '"test' '1.jpg"' '"test' '2.jpg"'

instead of :

> ls "test 1.jpg" "test 2.jpg"

My original script has an array of quoted filename (to prevent error on spaces) and must launch a command (with a pipe) to process these files. I couldn't find a solution, even using eval, to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't adding single quotes.

The `set -x` output (that I assume you are looking at) uses them to show the "words" they aren't actually there.

Your problem is that your filenames are being word split. You need to quote your array expansion and unless your filenames have double quotes in them drop the escaped quotes too.

Try:

```
filelist=("test 1.jpg" "test 2.jpg")
echo "${filelist[@]:0:2}"
ls "${filelist[@]:0:2}"|grep 1
```

Comment: Then you have your filename wrong (or it does actually have quotes in it or something). What does `ls -1Q` output in that directory?

Comment: Does not work :
ls: impossible d'accéder à test 1.jpg: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
(means can't file file, because quotes disepeared in your solution)
When I add again the escaped quotes it stil does not work :
filelist=("\"./test 1.jpg\"" "\"./test 2.jpg\"")
ls: impossible d'accéder à "./test 1.jpg": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: Actually it works, my mistake. Sorry ! Thanks a lot.